# Problem with identity in a interior product space when $w=1$ and $w^2=1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I need show this exercise:

Let $X$ is complex normed space with interior product and $w\in\mathbb{C}$ is a primitive root of $1$ of orden $n$.

Show that if $x,y\in X$ then  $$\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w^k\lVert x+w^k y \rVert^2.$$

**My solution:**

$(1)\,\,$ If $w\in\mathbb{C}$ is a primitive root of $1$ of orden $n$ then $n=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}:w^m=1\}$.

$(2)\,\,$  $w^m=1$ if and only if $n|m.\,\,\,$ ($n$ divides $m$, this fact is trivial.)

$(3)\,\,$  Since $w^n=1$ then $|w|^n=|w|\cdot |w|\cdots |w|=|w\cdot w\cdots w|=|w^n|=1\,\,$ then $\,\,|w|=1$.

Now:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w^k\lVert x+w^k y \rVert^2 
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w^k\langle x+w^k y, x+w^k y \rangle  \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\langle w^k x+w^{2k} y, x+w^k y\rangle  \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\langle w^kx, x \rangle + \langle w^k x, w^k y \rangle + \langle w^{2k}y, x \rangle + \langle w^{2k}y,w^{2k}y \rangle \right)\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k\langle x, x \rangle + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lvert w\rvert^{2k} \langle x, y \rangle + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^{2k} \langle y, x \rangle + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k \lvert w\rvert^{2k}\langle y,y \rangle \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \langle x, x \rangle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k + \langle x, y \rangle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lvert w\rvert^{2k}  + \langle y, x \rangle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^{2k}  + \langle y,y \rangle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k \lvert w\rvert^{2k} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \langle x, x \rangle\cdot 0+ \langle x, y \rangle\cdot n + \langle y, x \rangle\cdot 0  + \langle y,y \rangle\cdot 0 \right )\,\,\,\,\,(\ast)\\
&=  \langle x, y \rangle
\end{align*}

See the results in $(\ast)$. We know that:

$(i)$ $\hspace{0.5cm}$ For $w\neq 1$, $\displaystyle\,\,\,\,\,\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k=\dfrac{1-w^{n}}{1-w}=\dfrac{1-1}{1-w}=0.$

$(ii)$ $\hspace{0.5cm}$ $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lvert w\rvert^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1^{2k}=\dfrac{1-1}{1-w}=n.$

$(iii)$ $\hspace{0.5cm}$ For $w^2\neq 1$, $\displaystyle\,\,\,\,\,\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^{2k}=\dfrac{1-w^{2n}}{1-w^{2}}=\dfrac{1-(w^n)^2}{1-w^2}=\dfrac{1-1^2}{1-w^2}=0.$

$(i)$ $\hspace{0.5cm}$ For $w\neq 1$, $\displaystyle\,\,\,\,\,\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k|w|^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w^k=0.$

TO END THE SOLUTION I NEED JUSTIFY WHAT HAPPENS IF  $w=1$ and $w^2=1$.

BUT I HAVE NOT BEEN ABLE TO JUSTIFY THIS.

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1):

You have shown the statement for $w\not\in\{1,-1\}$, or the cases where $n>2$.

For the two remaining cases ($w=1,w=-1$), one can show that the statement is wrong.
To find a counterexample, use $X=\Bbb C$ and $x=y=1\in X=\Bbb C$,
and calculate the left-hand and right-hand side.